# Pivot Table in Python - Making column values into columns and ordering the columns in a specific way

Tags: python, pivot-table

I have a subset of a dataframe (actual dataframe is a lot larger with over 3000 rows) in Python such that

```
df <- data.frame(Name= c["John", "Karla", "Sandy", "John", "John", "Sandy"],       
Course Title = c["Training 2", "Training", "Training 2", "Training 5", "Training 2", "Training 2"],              
 Start Date= c["2022-11-08", "2022-11-25", "2023-02-09", "2023-03-15", "2023-03-19", "2023-03-19"], 
Completion Date= c["2022-11-09", "2022-11-28", "2023-02-09", "2023-03-20", "2023-03-21", "2023-03-19"]))
```

I want to pivot the dataframe in such a way that it groups by the Name, and each name has one single row, and the values in 'Course Title' are the column names, with the column values indicating whether each person completed the training, and with the start & completion dates following each Training column.

I want the result to be this with the columns in this order:

```
df_pivot <- data.frame(Name= c["John", "Karla", "Sandy"],       
Training = c[1, 1, 1],              
 Training_Start Date= c["2022-11-08", "2022-11-25", "2023-03-19"], 
Completion Date= c["2022-11-09", "2022-11-28", "2023-03-19"],
Training 2 = c[1, NaN, 1], 
Training 2_Start Date= c["2023-03-29", NaN, "2023-02-09"],
Training 2_Completion Date= c["2023-03-21", NaN, "2023-02-09"],
Training 5 = c[1, NaN, NaN],
Training 5_Start Date = c["2023-03-15", NaN, NaN]),
Training 5_Completion Date = c["2023-03-20", NaN, NaN])
```

This is what I've tried, but the last part of the code gives me an error.

```
# Pivot the dataframe
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='Course Title',
                          values=['Course Title', 'Start Date', 'Completion Date'],
                          aggfunc={'Course Title': 'count', 'Start Date': 'first', 'Completion Date': 'first'})

# Flatten the column names
df_pivot.columns = [f'{col[1]}_{col[0]}' if col[0] != '' else col[1] for col in df_pivot.columns]

# Reset the index
df_pivot = df_pivot.reset_index()

# Reorder the columns
columns = ['Name']
for title in df['Course Title'].unique():
    columns.append(title)
    columns.append(f'{title}_Start Date')
    columns.append(f'{title}_Completion Date')

df_pivot = df_pivot[columns]
```

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 df_pivot = df_pivot[columns]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in **getitem**(self, key)
2906             if is_iterator(key):
2907                 key = list(key)
-> 2908             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
2909
2910         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
1252             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
1253
-> 1254         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
1255         return keyarr, indexer
1256

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
1302             if raise_missing:
1303                 not_found = list(set(key) - set(ax))
-> 1304                 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
1305
1306             # we skip the warning on Categorical

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: posted full error

Comment: `take() does not accept boolean indexers` is not an error message. It's a comment before some other part of the code.

Comment: The error means that you have column names in `columns` that aren't columns of the dataframe.

Comment: Figured it out, thank you!